# “The Dear Departed” is “A Comedy in One Act” and “The Silver Box” is “A Comedy in Three Acts”. Is there some relation?

Tags: john-galsworthy, william-stanley-houghton, the-dear-departed, the-silver-box

“The Silver Box” was a play produced by John Galsworthy in 1906 and it gained huge popularity. It is not about comedy, Livens dialogues shows so much of reality of how big shots keep judges in their pockets. It is a three act play, and the author called it “A Comedy in Three Acts”.

“The Dear Departed” is a play, produced in 1908, in which the author, Stanley Houghton, satirizes the degradation of moral values in the British middle-class. In trying to grab the things belonging to grandfather the children completely disregard modesty, decency and filial obligation. This is one act play and the author calls it “A Comedy in One Act”.

Why the authors gave the secondary names to these plays? Is there a relation between these two plays?

Answer (score 1):

### Probably not

The subtitle of "A comedy in *n* acts" (extrapolated, "A(n) *x* in *n* *y*", where *x* is a type, *n* is a number of *y*, and *y* is a natural literary division such as acts or parts) is a fairly common one. The first part informs the reader that this is a comedy, and the second part informs the reader how many acts are in the play (which is correlated to length and plot structure). In that sense this is an entirely informational subtitle, without other meaning.

Some titles which use this structure, or a very similar one, chosen at random:

- [Brief Moment: A Comedy in Three Acts](https://thecarycollection.com/products/brief-moment-by-s-n-behrman)
- [Ralph Royster Doyster, a Comedy [In Five Acts, in Verse, by N. Udall]](https://www.worldofbooks.com/en-us/books/ralph-roister-doister/ralph-royster-doyster-a-comedy-in-five-acts-in-verse-by-n-udall/9781241533816)
- [Somebody and Nobody: A Play for Two Actors in Two Acts](https://bookshop.org/books/somebody-and-nobody-a-play-for-two-actors-in-two-acts/9781548888596)
- [The Guardian: A Comedy of Two Acts. As it is Perform'd at the Theatre-Royal in Drury-Lane](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Guardian.html?id=y69xzgEACAAJ)
- [The Fatal Jealousie. A Tragedy [in five acts and in verse. By N. Payne]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1241121443)
- [EuroTragedy: A Drama in Nine Acts](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/oso/9780199351381.001.0001/oso-9780199351381) (Notably, not a work of fiction - just using the common title structure)
- [The Druid; a Tragedy in Five Acts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1375075837)
- [A Possible Life: A Novel in Five Parts](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13722330-a-possible-life)
- A tweet, ["A comedy in n acts."](https://twitter.com/sd268/status/1184249088461754368)

I don't see any grand connection between the two plays you list, just a use of a common literary subtitle format.